# Something I'm not getting about geometric series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

The notation for geometric series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_0r^{n-1}} ={a_0}+{a_0}r+{a_0}r^2+{a_0}r^3+...  $$

and a geometric series will converge if $ -1<r<1 $ or if $ {a_0}=0 $.

In math class some time ago the teacher gave us the following problem:

> With what values of $x$ will the following series converge?
>   $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{3x}{x-4})^{n-1} $$

I tried to solve this by checking when $ -1<r<1 $ and when $ {a_0}=0 $, because those are the cases when it'll converge, but the teacher told me that $ {a_0}\neq0 $ because $0^0$ is undefined.

There is something I'm missing. What even actually is the ${a_0}$ in this case? And what is the $r$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, that is, in your problem,

$a_0=1$ and $r=\frac{3x}{x-4}$

Now the series will be convergent **iff** $$|r|<1$$
$$-1 \le r \le 1$$
$$-1 \le \frac{3x}{x-4} \le 1$$

We divide this into $2$ parts:

> $4-x \le 3x \le x-4\,$ when $x-4>0$
>
> and
>
> $\, 4-x\ge 3x \ge x-4 $ when $x-4<0$

From the first part, we get that

> $x \ge 1$ and $x \le -2$ and $x>4$.

From the second part, we get that

> $x \le 1$ and $x \ge -2$ and $x<4$.

But there is no such $x \in \mathbb{R}$ which satisfies all $3$ inequalities in the first part.

However, for $x \in [-2,1]$, all $3$ inequalities in the second part are satisfied and the value of $r$ lies between $-1$ and $1$.

Hence the series **does converge** for $x \in [-2,1]$.

Comment: You have either $x \geq 4$ and $4-x \leq 3x \leq x-4$, or $x<4$ and $4-x \geq 3x \geq x-4$. That's because you need to reverse inequalities when you multiply by a negative number. The latter pair of inequalities has nontrivial solutions.

Comment: are you sure about this? you are playing fast and loose with the inequalities here...you should get values of x between -2 and 1 for which the series converges

Comment: @Wouter Thanks a lot for helping. Hope I have fixed all the errors.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Fixed the errors. thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

Here $r=\frac{3x}{x-4}$ and $a_0=1$. Here and in a number of other places it is convenient to define $0^0=1$, so that everything makes sense when $r$ is anything in $(-1,1)$. The only reason I know of to justify not *always* saying $0^0=1$ is that $f(x,y)=x^y$ isn't continuous at $(0,0)$. Two examples to see this are $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^x = 1$ but $\lim_{x \to 0^+} x^{-\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}=1/e$.